# views.player widget for artists

Tags: spotify

i'm trying to get the player view working for an artist, but bar hacking around/manually reimplementing is there a better way to do this. below is the code that i have tried so far, taken from a stack overflow regarding the same thing for albums..  There is two problems with this, one the image doesn't show up/fallback to the album and two, when you try and play you get "Uncaught TypeError: Object Tin Hat Trio has no method 'get' "

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sp://import/css/eve.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sp://import/css/api.css">
</head>

<div id="artist-element"></div>
<script>
  var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
  var views = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/views');
  var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');
  models.Artist.fromURI('spotify:artist:5spC5WtEkxDbaIH7bGGX4m', function(artist) { 
    var p = new views.Player(); 
     p.context = artist; 
    document.getElementById('artist-element').appendChild(p.node); 
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The player object can only have a context of type `Album` or `Playlist`. Documentation [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/ca28d10757.html).